# enable tilestache logging

Tags: tilestache

I'm trying to get TileStache to generate some tiles but it is not making the call to the url template that I've specified. The TS docs say that I can enable logging in the config file by adding "logging": "debug". I've done so, but am not seeing any sort of logging anywhere. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can see the errors that are generated throught the web server log. if you are using apache wsgi, you can see then in the apache error log file. If you are using Werkzeug wsgi, you can see the errors that are generated throuth the console. Sometimes it helps to watch the responce to the request from firebug.
Most of the time the error is due to a missing dependency or in the wrong url template.